# Giving roles in JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

trying to make a JDA that gives roles on discord, however whenever i use getController() it puts a red line under it and there doesn't seem to be any libraries for ir , how else can i give a role, this is the code :

```java
    if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "mute")){

        if (args.length == 2) {
            Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById(args[1].replace("<@", "").replace(">", ""));
            Role role = event.getGuild().getRoleById("715670284023365824");

            if (!member.getRoles().contains(role)) {
                //Mute user
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("Muted " + args[1]).queue();
                event.getGuild().getController().addRolesToMember(member, role).complete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [Guild#addRoleToMember](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#addRoleToMember(net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member,net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Role)):

```java
Guild guild = event.getGuild();
Role role = guild.getRoleById(roleId);
Member member = guild.getMemberById(userId);
guild.addRoleToMember(member, role).queue();
```

Comment: guild is not recognized

Comment: Your "event" is also not recognized.